# Unable to get more than 7 days of tweets using search.twitter.com

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

Is it possible to get more than 6-9 days old data(tweets) using "https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" I've tried multiple things mentioned at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search but still not able to get more than 7 days old tweets.

I can see older tweets using the UI (twitter.com) but not through search.twitter.com query string which is my actual requirement.

Is it a known thing ? or am i missing something here? Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is a limitation of the Twitter Search API. You can find it documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search):

> - You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a
>     week.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Tweets older than a week Gnip offers historical Tweets all the way back to the very first Tweet from @jack.

https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/

Disclosure: I work at Gnip.